# POST json with bashscript using curl

Tags: json, bash, curl

I want to POST a json in bash script using curl but i am getting error that is dependent on the content..

I am getting error

```
Rebuilt URL to: "major":"1221",/
Illegal port number
Closing connection -1
curl: (3) Illegal port number
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
Rebuilt URL to: "minor":"32112",/
Illegal port number
Closing connection -1
curl: (3) Illegal port number
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 48
```

This works

```
#!/bin/bash

param='[{"timestamp":"value","sourceId":"fe28edab963de6788"}]' 

echo $param
curl -d $param -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Security-AuthKey: 84C0712F-856D-4EC7-B136-FA39B5FFE995" -H "Type: DATA" -H "Device: RaspberryPI" -X POST "https://test.api.com/webhook" -v
```

but this does not work...

```
#!/bin/bash

param='[{"timestamp":"1554895106","sourceId":"fe28edab963de6788","uuid":"F7826DA6-4FA2-4E98-8024-BC5B71E0893E", "major":"1221", "minor":"32112", "rssi":"-63","distance":".26307557616382837295"}]'


echo $param
curl -d $param -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Security-AuthKey: 84C0712F-856D-4EC7-B136-FA39B5FFE995" -H "Type: DATA" -H "Device: RaspberryPI" -X POST "https://test.api.com/webhook" -v
```

Comment: Add "double-quotes" around `$param` in the curl command. Your json is most certainly considered as multiple words, the first of which is associated with `-d` but the following of which are parsed as urls

Answer (score 2):

Like @Aaron said, the shell is splitting up your value because it has spaces in it. By default, Bash splits "words" by spaces, tabs, and newlines. `"weak quotes"` (double quotes) will escape this word-splitting process while still allowing you to expand variables.

```
curl -d "$param" ...
```